# How to relocate MC clubhouse

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I bought a club house high in Blaine county and now I want to move it to somewhere in the city (or nearer to) because I bought a meth business that is 5.7km away, and I don't really want to make the long drive everytime.

If I go to buy a new one, I don't get the option to sell my current one - like you do when buying houses.

How can I, even with businesses, relocate my club house?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum post](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/220718007-Can-i-sell-my-clubhouse-or-buy-another-one-) you can sell your clubhouse and buy a new one with reducted cost.

[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/55zuno/anyone_have_two_clubhouses/) has the same question as the forum post and apparently you just trade them in.

If this is not happening it could be a bug in the game.

Comment: Thanks for the info, *+1*. I'll accept when I can verify buying a new clubhouse tonight gives you some money back `:)`